# AppleScript SL to ML Issue (compatibility error?)

Tags: snow-leopard, macos, applescript

I've written the following script in Applescript in Snow Leopard, and I tried to use it in Mountain Lion, but to no avail (doesn't work). The script watches a folder for added files, and if the filetype matches, it will scp it to a server.

It runs great, no errors on Snow Leopard. When it's run in ML it spits back the error (in console):

`AppleScript Runner: CPSGetFrontProcess(): This call is deprecated and should not be called anymore.`

I'm almost positive this has something to do with the way the script is written. I have tried copying & pasting into a new script in mountain lion, and then saving that. Doesn't work either.

Here is the code itself, any insight as to what call is working wrong?

```
on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving the_files

--set login vars
set fileExt to "zip"
set scpIP to "blah"
set scpUser to "blah"
set scpDest to "/home/blah"
set scpPort to "1234"

--repeat on each file that is added to the folder
repeat with each_file in the_files
    set filename to name of (info for each_file)
    tell application "Finder"
        --check extension, if match, scp. else, error.
        if name extension of each_file is fileExt then
            try
                do shell script "scp -p" & scpPort & " " & scpUser & "@" & scpIP & ":" & scpDes
                move each_file to trash
            end try
        end if
    end tell
end repeat

end adding folder items to
```

Comment: What line is the script executing when it throws that error?

Comment: Not sure, haven't spent much time on it in ML yet, was having a friend test for me. Just got my own ML box, going to test & post results here.

Answer (score 1):

this might fix it, failing that can you post the contents of the plist files from ~/Library/LaunchAgents

```
on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving the_files

--set login vars
set fileExt to "zip"
set scpIP to "blah"
set scpUser to "blah"
set scpDest to "/home/blah"
set scpPort to "1234"

--repeat on each file that is added to the folder
repeat with each_file in the_files
    set filename to name of (info for each_file)
    --check extension, if match, scp. else, error.
    if name extension of each_file is fileExt then
        try
            do shell script "scp -p" & scpPort & " " & scpUser & "@" & scpIP & ":" & scpDes
            tell application "System Events" to move each_file to trash
        end try
    end if
end repeat
end adding folder items to
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment - I actually posted on another forum and ended up with this exact script, which worked. 
There is a bizarre (and poorly documented, surprise) issue within OSX that spits back a depreciated call regardless of what code is there for this type of script. The script was too slow, so I gave in and am writing a menu bar application to do the same, it'll be a bit more robust :)